# Al desplegar mi aplicacion con Netlify no se obtienen los datos de la API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

Tengo un problema con el despliegue de mi aplicación React, la cual usa la api.weatherstack para obtener información del clima. Cuando ejecuto en el servidor http://localhost:3000/ la información es obtenida y mostrada sin problemas en la pantalla, despues de realizada una petición axios al endpoint correspondiente a la ubicación geografica, pero al momento de desplegarla por medio de Netlify a la siguiente dirección https://react-countries-data.netlify.app/, no obtengo ningún error durante el proceso, sin embargo los datos del clima no son mostrados en la pantalla.

La clave de mi API la he almacenado en una variable de entorno llamada REACT_APP_API_KEY dentro de un archivo .env en la raiz del directorio principal.

Comment: Hola Martin, Bienvenido a stackofverflow. deberias de poner algo de código para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Hace muy poco tuve un problema parecido, y sin llegar a ver tu código, en mi caso pude descubrir que venía por un status code...(426) profundizando un poco mas, pude ver que la api que consumía (free) en el plan gratuito que ofrece "developer plan" solo envia respuestas a localhost... para enviar respuestas a navegadores era necesario un plan de pago.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero con esto poder ayudar a futuros

Answer (score 0):

buscando en ingles alguuien sugirio que se debe a variables de entorno[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085169/react-app-working-on-localhost-but-not-working-on-netlify-deploy-because-the-api

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/398046)